# How to remove copyright footer from latex acm template

Tags: templates

I am trying to delete a footer copyright from the first page of my rapport using Latex acm large template but it still appearing in tjis way (see screenshot please):

> Vol. 1, No. 1, Article . Publication date: January

```
    \documentclass[acmlarge,screen]{acmart}


\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08emT\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\copyrightyear{}
\acmYear{}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcopyright{none}
\acmConference[Woodstock '18]{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection}{June 03--05, 2018}{Woodstock, NY}
\acmBooktitle{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection, June 03--05, 2018, Woodstock, NY}
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-9999-9/18/06}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mwe}    % loads »blindtext« and »graphicx«
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\let\@authorsaddresses\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}
```

[image]
**EDIT:**
Firstly, thanks to all the replies. Due to my new account, I am not able to add comments but I will answer here:
The article will be not published, it is only for internal between me and an examinat and by the way, he imposes the template and also the removing of all the copyright. Otherwise, I would to use my own template.
I've edited the code to be more clear for you :) but I am sure what is inside the document is not related to the problem, it is only a normal text.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) If you have been asked to use a template, you do not change the template. That is basically disrespectful towards the editors.

Comment: If it's to be published in some magazine, I would imagine you have to give them the tex file and they will compile it in yourself. If it's for personal use, I can't imagine it being disrespectful to remove the text "Vol. 1. No. Article. Publication date". That is not a copyright message. Removing a copyright message _is_ very disrespectful.

Comment: ... and what's really missing is a compileable example - something we can copy and paste and work with it. So far we have to "fix" your code by adding the `\begin{document}` and so on. More people would help if you would add the remaining code!

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
\documentclass[acmlarge,screen,nonacm]{acmart}
```

according to

[LaTeX documentation - Association for Computing Machinery](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf)

Comment: First, `screen` means `A screen version: hyperlinks are colored`. Thus, there is not really related to the question. Second, `nonacm` did solve the problem which means `Use the class typeseing options for a non-ACM document, which will not include the conference/journal header and footers or permission statements`.

Comment: `nonacm` is the relevant argument, at least on older templates

Comment: Thanks for the response, `nonacm` is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Even without being disrespectful to the editors (as @daleif or @Tommiie correctly points out), or the ACM as such, if-- just for the sake of exploring the (hidden?) features of LaTeX-- someone wants to incidentally play with its tools, such as implementing mild hacks on a `documentclass` like `acmart`, I would suggest something like:

- Finding `acmart.cls` from the installed latex folder or from any web source
- Saving a copy of it in the folder where the working `.tex` file is located
- Opening `acmart.cls` with any text editor
- Finding the text "Publication Date" (probably it's there as `\fancyfoot[...]{...}` in several places)
- Changing them to say, "Date of Publication"
- Compiling the `.tex` file again and noticing changes in the output if any.